# How to verify return value from MySQLi->prepare()

Tags: php, mysqli

I've searched high and low for an answer to this question, to no avail.  I reach out to you my fellow coders.  :-)

I have the following, seemingly simple PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT marketid, type, quantity, price, datetime, bundleid, state, stoplossprice FROM orders WHERE type = ? AND state = ?";
$stmt = $login->mySQLi->prepare($query);
if(!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($login->mySQLi));
}
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $strOrderType, $strOrderState);
if($stmt)
{
    if(!$stmt->execute())
    {
        // Return an error
    }
}
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($marketid, $ordertype, $quantity, $buyprice, $buydatetime, $bundleid, $orderstate, $stoplossprice);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // Do something with the returned data
}
$stmt->close();
```

I also have almost the exact same code several other places, and in the other places it works.  But, for some reason it's terminating when executing the `execute()` statement.

Also, after executing the `prepare()` statement, `$stmt->affected_rows` equals -1.

I read in the MySQLi docs, a value of -1 means "-1 indicates that the query returned an error".  But, for I can't figure out how to output the error message from `$stmt`.  `$stmt->errno` and `$stmt->error` have no values.

I've also checked the log file for MySQL and it shows the following:

> 141117 21:21:39 222 Prepare   SELECT marketid, type, quantity, price, datetime, bundleid, state, stoplossprice FROM orders WHERE type = ? AND state = ? 
>   222 Statistics 
>   223 Statistics
>   141117 21:21:54 222 Statistics
>   223 Statistics
>   141117 21:21:55 222 Statistics
>   223 Statistics
>   141117 21:21:56 222 Statistics
>   223 Statistics
>   141117 21:21:57 222 Execute   SELECT marketid, type, quantity, price, datetime,
>   bundleid, state, stoplossprice FROM orders WHERE type = 'Buy' AND state = 'Pending'
>   223 Quit
>   222 Close stmt
>   222 Quit

Help me Obi-wan Kenobi, you're my only hope (and yah, it's late, I'm feeling a bit slappy)!

Comment: You should check for errors after execute.

Comment: The `prepare` do not affect any rows in the database, so the -1 result is expected. You should check for errors after the `execute`. If there are errors - paste here so we can help.

Comment: The call to '$stmt->execute()` causes the program to terminate unexpectedly.  So, I'm not able to see the return value from `$stmt->execute()`.  I probably should have included this in my original question.

Comment: Here's some more, hopefully helpful, info.  I tried using a static string from the select statement with the same results.  Also tried using `MySQLi->query()`, but the program terminates when `MySQLi->query()` is executed.   I've coded many other select, insert and update statements using almost identical code.  I'm truly stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I was, at long last, able to find the answer.

Prior to executing the code I posted, I was executing other MySQL statements.  In those statements I executed `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);`.

As I learned in the PHP docs, one should be careful when calling `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);`.  Here's an excerpt from the documentation of `mysqli_report()`, explaining the issue:

"Be very careful using this function - it's a per-process setting.
If your server is set up to reuse a single PHP process for multiple requests, that means the last setting of this function in any script will affect all other scripts using mysqli.
To be safe always call  at the end of a script. The CGI version of PHP is probably safe from this."

I added `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);` to the end of the 1st MySQL statements and now it works like a charm.  Thanks PHP docs!! And thanks to sectus and Antoan Milkov for your efforts as well!!